# Python: Efficiently interpolate from an irregular grid to a regular grid in 2D

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, interpolation

I have some data points in an irregularly-spaced 2d grid which I'd like to interpolate onto a regular grid.  For example, imagine the source data comes from a fisheye camera: [image]
<sub>(source: [starizona.com](https://starizona.com/acb/basics/optics/distortion.jpg))</sub>

**Examples of irregular source grids.  Note... these are just examples - in general source data may be distorted in different ways too - but still come from a grid.**

```
# Source Data
x_src  # A (n_src_rows, n_src_cols) array of x-coordinates of points
y_src  # A (n_src_rows, n_src_cols) array of y-coordinates of points
       # (x_src, y_src) form an irregular grid.  i.e. if you were to plot the lines connecting neighbouring points, no lines would ever cross.
f_src  # A (n_src_rows, n_src_cols) array of values.

# Interpolation Points: 
x_dst  # An (n_dest_cols) sorted array of x-coordinates of columns in a regular grid
y_dst  # An (n_dest_rows) sorted array of y-coordinates of rows in a regular grid.

# Want to calculate:
f_dst  # An (n_dest_rows, n_dest_cols) array of interpolated data on the regular grid defined by x_dst, y_dst
```

Thus far, I've been using [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), and flattening my source points into a 1D array, but it's a bit slow, because it takes no advantage of the grid structure of the source data points (only the destination data points).  It also interpolates in regions that are not inside adjacent source grid points (this happens if the boundaries of the source grid are concave (as in the left figure).

Is there a function in SciPy/opencv or some similar library that interpolates efficiently when the source data comes in an irregularly-spaced grid?

Comment: From an optimization-perspective: there is no (good) approach without you regularizing the problem (or it's ill-conditioned). You need to define assumptions about your possible distortions.

Comment: There is a fairly strong assumption - the source data comes in a grid. No other point will fall in the triangle bettween `(xy[i,j], xy[i+1,j], xy[i,j+1])`.  Scipy's `griddata` does not use this knowledge (it makes no prior assumptions on the structure of source data).

Answer (score 0):

Well it's still not optimal, because it makes no use of the fact that the source data is known to lie along a grid, but the best approach I've found so far is to use SciPy's NearestNDInterpolator, which is based on a KDTree:

```
import scipy.interpolate 

def fast_interp_irregular_grid_to_regular(
        x_dst,  # type: ndarray(dst_size_x)  # x-values of columns in the destination image.
        y_dst,  # type: ndarray(dst_size_y)  # y-values of rows in the destination image
        x_src,  # type: ndarray(src_size_y, src_sixe_x)   # x-values of data points
        y_src,  # type: ndarray(src_size_y, src_size_x)   # y-values of data points
        f_src,  # type: ndarray(src_size_y, src_size_x, n_dim)  # values of data points.
        fill_value = 0,  # Value to fill in regions outside pixel hull
        zero_edges = True,  # Zero the edges (ensures that regions outside source grid are zero)
    ):  # type: (...) -> array(dst_size_y, dst_size_x, n_dim)  # Interpolated image
    """
    Do a fast interpolation from an irregular grid to a regular grid.  (When source data is on a grid we can interpolate
    faster than when it consists of arbitrary points).

    NOTE: Currently we do not exploit the fact that the source data is on a grid.  If we were to do that, this function
    could be much faster.
    """
    assert zero_edges in (False, True, 'inplace')

    univariate = f_src.ndim==1
    if univariate:
        f_src = f_src[:, None]
    else:
        assert f_src.ndim==3

    if zero_edges:
        if zero_edges is True:
            f_src = f_src.copy()
        f_src[[0, -1], :] = fill_value
        f_src[:, [0, -1]] = fill_value
    interp = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator(
        x = np.hstack([x_src.reshape(-1, 1), y_src.reshape(-1, 1)]),
        y = f_src.reshape(-1, f_src.shape[-1]),
    )
    grid_x, grid_y = np.meshgrid(x_dst, y_dst)
    z = interp((grid_x, grid_y)).reshape((len(y_dst), len(x_dst), f_src.shape[-1]))
    return z
```

Answer (score -1):

How about [scipy.interpolate.interp2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)?

Comment: From [the Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html), it either requires the source points to come in a regular grid, or requires just a flat vector of source points.  So it cannot take advantage of an irregular grid of source points.  I've already tried this function and it runs very slowly.

Comment: Can you define a function that maps your irregular points to a regular grid? If so you could map x_src, y_src and x_dst, y_dst and perform the interpolation using a regular grid.

Comment: You mean a function `x_newsrc, y_newsrc = f(x_src, y_src)` where `(x_newsrc, y_newsrc)` form a regular grid?  Maybe I could, but then to be correct I'd have to apply the same function to my destination grid, and then I end up with a regular source grid and an irregular destination grid... and the same problem.

Comment: Yes you would need to apply the function the `x_dst` and `y_dst` as well. Having an irregular destination grid is *not* the same problem.

Comment: One thing worth noting is that this desired function, if applied for Geographical coordinate data (i.e.: longitude and latitude), it must account for geodesic distance. Therefore, a linear (or even a polynomial, splines, etc.) function won't return correct interpolated results.